# Data Columns showing Null value after inserting data into database laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have created a form using bootstrap to insert data into my database. I have created a model and set a fillable array and made a controller and set all the routes the problem I am facing is that when I fill the form and click on the Submit buttons it shows the alert message that data added successfully but when I check my database it is showing null value because i have set my migrations to nullable and when i set my migrations to default it shows the default value and when i dont set any thing it shows errors. I am new to laravel.

This is my form

```
<div class="mt-4 mx-5">
    <h2>Add News</h2>
    @if (session('news_success'))
            <div class="alert alert-success">
                {{session('news_success')}}
            </div>
    @endif
    <form action="{{route('news/store')}}" class="mt-4" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="title">Title</label>
            <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control @error('title') is-invalid  @enderror" >
            @error('title')
                <span class="text-danger">News Title is required</span>
            @enderror
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="content">Content</label>
                    <textarea name="content" cols="30" rows="5" class="form-control @error('content') is-invalid  @enderror"></textarea>
                    @error('content')
                        <span class="text-danger">Content is required</span>
                    @enderror
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="title">Image</label>
            <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control @error('image') is-invalid  @enderror">
            @error('image')
                <span class="text-danger">Image is required</span>
            @enderror
        </div>

       
        <input type="submit" value="Add News" class="btn btn-dark">
    </form>
</div>
```

This is my Model file

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\News;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class News extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'news';
    protected $fillable = [
        'news_title',
        'news_content',
        'news_Image',
    ];

}
```

This is my controller function

```
public function store(Request $request){
    $data = $request->validate([
        'title' =>'required',
        'image' =>'required',
        'content' =>'required',
    ]);

    News::create($data);
    return back()->with('news_success', 'News Added Successfully');
}
```

This is my routes file

```
Route::get('news',[NewsController::class, 'index'])->name('news');
Route::get('news/create',[NewsController::class,'createNews'])->name('news/create');
Route::post('news/store',[NewsController::class,'store'])->name('news/store');
```

I have also used the guarded array and I have also used the save method way to save the data when
I have used the save method it show the error that request is not callable. I am using laravel 8 version

Answer (score 0):

in your model make fillable the same as names of in your input in your blade

your model should be like this

```
protected $table = 'news';
    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'content',
        'image',
    ];
```

your blade like this

```
<form action="{{route('news/store')}}" class="mt-4" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="title">Title</label>
            <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control @error('title') is-invalid  @enderror" >//name is title same as in fillable in model 
            @error('title')
                <span class="text-danger">News Title is required</span>
            @enderror
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="content">Content</label>
                    <textarea name="content" cols="30" rows="5" class="form-control @error('content') is-invalid  @enderror"></textarea>//name is content same as in fillable in model 
                    @error('content')
                        <span class="text-danger">Content is required</span>
                    @enderror
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="title">Image</label>
            <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control @error('image') is-invalid  @enderror">// name is image same as in fillable in model 
            @error('image')
                <span class="text-danger">Image is required</span>
            @enderror
        </div>

       
        <input type="submit" value="Add News" class="btn btn-dark">
    </form>
```

also in your controller  do $request->all() like this

```
public function store(Request $request){
    $data = $request->validate([
        'title' =>'required',
        'image' =>'required',
        'content' =>'required',
    ]);

    News::create($data);
    return back()->with('news_success', 'News Added Successfully');
}
```